# how can I read two object from two different file, using SequenceInputStream in java

Tags: java

```
FileInputStream FIS1=new FileInputStream("f1.txt");
FileInputStream FIS2=new FileInputStream("f2.txt");
SequenceInputStream SIS=new SequenceInputStream(FIS1,FIS2);
ObjectInputStream OIS=new ObjectInputStream(SIS);
Object[0]=(One)OIS.readObject();
Object[1]=(One)OIS.readObject(); //this line give error
```

The error is

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid
>   type code: AC     at
>   java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
>     at
>   java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:33)

How to solve this please help me I'm new in java.
[Full Code and Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrW8q.png)

Comment: Unrelated: read about java naming conventions. Variable names go camelCase, ALL_UPPER is for constants only. And never ever name an array `Object`. Use names that mean something, and dont "re-use" names out of the standard libraries! Plus: no point in putting code into images. SImply make sure that your question contains all relevant details as nicely formatted text.

Comment: And just for the record: when you create TWO ObjectInputStreams, directly from each file input stream, then it works?

Answer (score 1):

You can't construct an ObjectInputStream from a SequenceInputStream because each file starts with a special file header to indicate it's a Java Object stream. If you use a SequenceInputStream, the second file's header is unexpectedly encountered in the middle of the stream.

You have to construct separate ObjectOutputStream instances for each one of your files.

By the way, a few comments based on your code:

1. Use Java code style conventions. There are a few different ones around, but they only differ in minor details with many conventions that are followed by all. Google "Java code style convention" to find a few. Using accepted conventions helps others understand your code.
2. Give variables and classes descriptive names (eg class UserData instead of One, userDataArray instead of Object).
3. Learn the Single Responsibility Principle. Your class One seems to two more than one thing: hold data AND do input/output.
4. You shouldn't call your files with a ".txt" extension, since they are not text files; they are binary files with a special format specific to Java ObjectInputStream.

Comment: thank you guys I will keep that mind for better coding